# Populating MySQLi result into an associative array

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to save a result of SQL query into an associative array in PHP.

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT  `id`, `age` FROM `emp`"); 
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $rows[]=$row;
}
```

But this is creating an associative array inside another array! How can I fix this?

Comment: So the output is like if you want to access the data you need to do `$rows[0]['id']` right?

Comment: yes exactly! `$rows[0]`

Comment: That is how it suppose to work. if you directly need the data in current loop then you can use `$row['id']`

Comment: Otherwise wherever you are using this `$rows` you need to give index or iterate over it.

Comment: _"But this creating an Associative array inside an other array!"_ - That's what `$rows[] = $row; ` does. `$row` is an array which you push into another array `$rows`, so yes, that would give you one array per row inside the main array. What result are you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are querying all data from `` `emp` `` table and creating new array form the result inside `while` loop. You can print `$rows` outside while loop using `foreach` or `for` loop or print inside `while` loop without creating new `$rows` array. If you are accepting one result form that query please use where clause to specify your desire row and make `limit 1`. And Do not use `while` loop

```
// outside while loop
foreach($rows as $row) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

or

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT  `id`, `age` FROM `emp` WHERE `id`=1 LIMIT 1"); 
$row = $result->fetch_assoc()
```